# How to do metaprogramming or conditional compilation in function level instead of platform in GoLang?

Tags: go, design-patterns, compilation

I am trying to build a binary that will contain different modules, but at the same time, I want the user to be able to choose what modules will be included in the generated binary.

I have also asked in SE stackoverflow: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/378319/building-object-with-arbitrary-functionalities

I think this is out of my knowledge and I might need some help with this.

I am thinking about writing another Go Program that strip out functions from the go files before compilation. I have never done/heard about this before and it seems to be a bit hacky. Just wondering what will be the best approach to this problem.

Thanks! I have also attached a testing code that I used.

```
package main

import (
"strings"
"fmt"
"bufio"
"os"
"reflect"
"./f"
"./g"
)



func main() {
    // assume this is user input, enable f and disable g
    var options = map[string]bool{
        "f":true,
        "g":false,
    }

    // a map for all the functions
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "f": f.F,
        "g": g.G,
    }
    // remove disabled function from the map
    for k,v := range options {
        if v == false{
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }


    // and now if user wanna use function g, it will return not ok since it is disabled in setting
    // and function f will work
    fmt.Println("Enter Options(f/g)")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    user_input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    user_input = strings.TrimSuffix(user_input, "\n")
    fmt.Println(user_input)
    // take input from user... f
    if x,ok := m[user_input]; ok {
        function := reflect.ValueOf(x)
        function_input := make([]reflect.Value, 1)
        function_input[0]=reflect.ValueOf("123")
        function.Call(function_input)
        fmt.Println("OK")
   } else {
        fmt.Println("Option doesnt exist or disabled.")
   }
}
```

Package g

```
package g

import "fmt"

func G(p string) { // removed second arguemt
    fmt.Println("function g parameters:", p)
}
```

Package f

```
package f

import "fmt"

func F(p string) {
    fmt.Println("function f parameter:", p)
}
```

What I did was just run `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build test.go` and run `objdump -t test` to see if the function is included in the binary after flipping the option values.

And you can see f and g are included in the binary, no matter the value of the option is true or false.

```
080bef10 g     F .text       000000a7 main.f
080befc0 g     F .text       000000c0 main.g
080bf080 g     F .text       00000544 main.main
080bf5d0 g     F .text       00000052 main.init
```

Comment: I don't know go well enough to answer.  But in order to have only the needed function in the binary, I think can youse the linking approach by having  f and g each in a separate package (that's the degree of granularity for linkers). Then you have to assemble your map in a third package, which would offer to your client a registration method but doesn't know neither f nor g.  Finally, in main you'd call the map registration for the needed functions only.  You can then simulate the result for different clients registration more or less of your functions.

Comment: @Christophe I will give that a try now and see if I can get a different result. That's basically what I did in the example code, but all of them are just in the same package.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for build tags: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Build Constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)
You need to place each of your modules in separate file(s) . They don't need to be in a separate package.

At the top of each file in the `foo` module you place:

```
// +build foo
```

And at top of each file in the `bar` package you place

```
// +build bar
```

You can now build your binary with the foo module,

```
go build -tags foo ...
```

Or both

```
go build -tags 'foo bar' ...
```

Comment: But this requires changes to the main file as well.. Let say I wanna build without package f. I have to change the code in the main file.

Comment: You need to come up with some scheme where the modules register themselves in an init() function (e.g. place a function in a global map that you can call from your main,) or use reflection to find modules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think that's what I am doing in my example code. `m` is the map for all the functions. But now if we compile without f, we have to remove the mapping and that is at code level. So, it means we have to strip out the code first before we build the program?

Comment: I have thought about having a dummy function for each of them, but that doesn't sound like the best solution.

Comment: @TimothyLeung Your map would be empty to start with, and it would be global. Then do e.g. `registry.globalMap["g"] = G` in an [init](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init) function in your `g` module

Comment: Ah great! Not a bad idea aye. I will give it a try :) THanks

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to get this to work.. I still realise the main package have to import `f` and `g` even I am using the new approach.

Comment: @TimothyLeung If you want to use modules this way without any static coupling to the included modules, you need some sort of abstraction. It depends on how complicated your modules are. If they're simple, you can just stuff a function pointer with a signature that is not dependent on the module into `globalMap` and call that from your main package. If they're more complicated, you might need to create a common interface for your modules that you place in `globalMap` and interact with that from main.